# Send xlsxwriter excel file for download via json

Tags: php, json, excel

My code is in PHP.
If I save on my server the file generated by Xlswriter everything works fine. But if I try to send it for download thru JSON, using $writer->writeToStdOut(), I get a msg that the file is corrupted. What am I doing wrong?

This is the part of my code that generates the excel file:

```
$writer = new XLSXWriter();
$sheet_name = '360' ;
$writer->writeSheetHeader($sheet_name, $row_headers); 
$writer->writeSheetRow($sheet_name, $row); 
$filename = $lastname . ".xlsx";
header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Disposition, Content-Type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");filename="'.XLSXWriter::sanitize_filename($filename).'"');
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET'); header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');

$writer->writeToStdOut();`
```

I first created the code to write to a file on the server using xlzswriter. Everything was fine. Then I tried to make the file availbale for download sending it to a client pgm using JON. At this point I get an error "file corrupted". Perhaps I'm not using the right method... In the past I used fopen php://output to send csv files for download and was working fine.

Comment: What JSON are you talking about?

Comment: I'm sending the file to a client app thru JSON